# Триггер для диалогового окна

Tags: jquery, события, html

Задача простая. Есть input который вызывает диалоговое окно для выбора файла с компьютера. Как правильно поставить trigger для момента, когда пользователь в этом окне нажимает ОК?

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('input[type=file]').val() != '')
{
  //действия
}
```

т.е. если инпут с файлом не пуст - кнопка была нажата! trigger лишний раз не дернется если файл не был выбран!

Comment: Нет, не работает. В input пусто даже когда я файл выбираю.